# Javascript Combination Method

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations

i need help to build function that gets two params: "chars", "combinationLength"
example:

```
 var chars = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; //can be also strings
 var combinationLength = 3;
 generateCombinations(chars, combinationLength){
 }
```

the output should be:
111
112
113
114
115
116
121
122
etc...

it means to take all the chars and create combinations,
hope i was clearly ;]

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service ... it is up to you to show your attempts and people here help you fix **your code**

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with a temporary array and a check for length.

```js
function generateCombinations(array, length) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(a) {
        var r = this.concat(a);
        if (r.length === length) {
            result.push(r);
            return;
        }
        array.forEach(iter, r);
    }, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(generateCombinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to code by yourself, check out this gist
https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596

If you are looking for a solution in Node.js, you can use this library,
https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics. Or extract the function you need from the library

Answer (score 0):

Nina Scholz Thanks for reply works well!

```js
function generateCombinations(array, length) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(a) {
        var r = this.concat(a);
        if (r.length === length) {
            result.push(r);
            return;
        }
        array.forEach(iter, r);
    }, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(generateCombinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```